# VS Installer causes BSOD when repairing VS19 Community

Tags: bsod, visual-studio

Yesterday (7-7-2020), I tried to launch Visual Studio 2019, but received a popup "Setup is not complete for this installation of Visual Studio". To fix this, I updated VS Installer and then ran the repair function on VS19. I left it running and got dinner. When I got back, my computer was at the login screen. I logged back in and all my apps were closed. I then checked "C:\Windows\minidump" for new log files and found one for that day. Today I analyzed this log file and found that the BSOD was caused by an UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION. I started the installer back up to repair VS19 and it ran 10 minutes before causing another BSOD with the same exception. I have uploaded the crash dumps to [GitHub](https://github.com/AwesomeCronk/CrashDumps) for review. The installer version that is causing this issue is `2.6.2037.624` and the version of VS19 it is attempting to repair is `16.6.3`. How do I fix this issue?

I have tried reporting this as a bug, but when I do, I am told to use Visual Studio's built-in "Report a Problem" feature. At this point I cannot open Visual Studio. I am on Windows 10 1903 build 18362.657.

Edit:
After analyzing both crash dumps using WinDBG, I found that the assembly instruction that triggered the error was this: `mov     ecx,dword ptr [r8]`. This was the same in both files. WinDBG marked this as the FAULTING_IP.

Comment: With prior versions of Visual Studio, the broad fix (at least for some installation problems) was to simply use an older version of the installer.

Comment: how do I roll back the installer?

Comment: @AwesomeCronk - It would not work in the case you describe.  The VS installer is updated all the time.

Comment: @Ramhound I guess I just need to wait for the next update to the VS Installer, then.

Comment: @AwesomeCronk - I was able to find a similar report [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/140738/bsod-during-update-rendered-whole-vs-unusable.html) which suggested running [` %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe -i`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/cleaning-up-corrupt-visual-studio-instances/).  If you cannot find the executable, it might be best to download the current bootstrap, and try that.

Comment: @AwesomeCronk - You are going to wait weeks to solve this problem?  I don't know why the problem is the the installer is running into a corrupt file, doesn't know what to do, and causes a BSOD.  You still have to fix that problem before any version of the installer will work. [Here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/983062/multiple-bsods-when-using-microsoft-visual-studio.html) indicates just reinstalling might help

Comment: I have run into the problem with the installer failing before. It caused a different issue, though, and I ended up resetting Windows to fix it. I will try installcleanup and see what that does.

Answer (score 1):

Based on one of @Ramhound's comments, I have managed to repair VS19 by running installcleanup with no arguments and downloading a fresh installation from the Visual Studio download page. It did not install Python, though, but that is a different issue and opens the route for improvement on my side of things.

Edit later on: I finally replaced the hard drive. That fixed it.